How to wire MTS gen panel with Tesla Backup Gateway 2 and main panel
I am preparing to finish my basement and as part of that, finishing the electrical. Looking to see if the Manual Transfer Switch (MTS) generator panel as I have proposed to use it works. The main service panel was replaced a few years ago as I was out of space to support my basement finish and wasn't to current code (No AFCI breakers). I want to move my HVAC circuits off the main panel and move them over to the MTS 4 space, 8 circuit panel. Both the MTS panel and main panel will be fed by the Tesla Backup Gateway 2 that is now going to take the 150 amp feed from the entrance panel.
The backup gateway as I understand it, is designed to take the feed coming in from the entrance panel and act as the ATS to power the backup load, which in this case will be the entire main service panel. It also lets non-backup loads pass-thru and in this case will go to the MTS. The new Powerwall 3 backup battery will take up residence in one of the two, two space spots on the main panel vacated by moving the HVAC (60 amp circuit) and power the main panel. The other two space spot vacated by the upstairs HVAC will be a 30 amp circuit to the MTS panel.
The use case I’m attempting to resolve is my HVAC loads must move as the single powerwall cannot handle all loads and HVAC initial surge in a peak busy hour outage scenario (Powerwall will scram and shutdown since it can't handle it). Further, I don't want my HVACs using expensive UPS power and draining its limited battery supply needed for the home.
At the same time, I want to be able to utilize my portable gen to take on the HVAC, my main level HVAC anyways, and provide any excess power from my genset to the main panel to conserve battery draw. I will further probably want access to the powerwall from the mts panel to help in the initial HVAC surge when I power it up as I can only handle 8KW surge. The 30 amp circuit between the MTS and main panel I think will always need to be locked off until an outage. Once I’ve flipped the MTS to generator mode and turned off the HVAC breakers, can finally start the generator and open the circuit to the main panel. At that point I can bring one of my two HVAC units online.
I’ve provided a diagram below. Does this make sense? Apologies for being long winded in advance as I'm trying to get all of this out of my head. I’ll work with an electrician at some point, but wanted to first see if this passes the straight face test here. Thanks!


What is not clear to me is interlock. Essentially, is there any single thing that prevents the generator from backfeeding the utility? Because if so, this doesn't work (code/safety). The way I see it here, if the Tesla Backup Gateway 2 is linking everything to utility power then if you turn the generator on it will either backfeed to the utility (if utility has an outage) or get utterly confused and meltdown (if utility is providing power). Usually the generator is connected in a path that can either have generator or utility. Too many loops here to guarantee that, I think.

@manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact thanks! that's what I am unclear of as well and will have to research it specifically. I know at least for the circuits being backed up, in this case the whole main panel, it prevents backfeeding as its purpose is to prevent power from powerwall feeding back into the grid. The MTS panel prevents backfeeding through its circuit to the gateway by design the minute I switch from its utility feed through the gateway to the genset circuit. For safety, I would need to lockout the 30 amp circuit to the main panel until I've switched to generator power.

@JGrant -- have you looked at replacing the HVAC with an inverter-based unit? (most mini-splits use inverter technology, and you can also get inverter compressors in the traditional North American outdoor unit form factor as well, including units that work with standard thermostats)

This won't fly due to parallel paths (and possible confusion from the Powerwall)
The configuration in your diagram is a non-starter for two reasons:

It violates the "no paralleling" rules in NEC 300.3(B) and 310.10(H) due to the presence of the inter-panel tie between the MTS and house load subpanel.  (This also creates issues with stray magnetic field emissions.)

Powerwalls may not like charging off the generator as a "sideload" feed -- charging Powerwalls from generators is generally poorly supported (blame Tesla, as its by no means an inherent restriction of AC battery tech)


How to get what you want (hopefully)
My understanding, though, is that you'll need to have the MTS (probably a breaker interlock) upstream of the Powerwall, so that the Backup Gateway thinks it's a substitute grid and will try to charge off the generator power.  This does mean you won't be able to have the Powerwalls sell to the grid, though.
That said, if you order your Backup Gateway with the panelboard option, you should be able to fit a BR230B for the generator breaker in the bottom left position, a CSR2150N for the panelboard main, and then use a BRMIKCSR interlock to get you your breaker interlock.  This does require the use of a BRSF150 subfeed block in the panelboard and some 2/0 aluminum THHN or XHHW-2 to jumper from the interlocked panel to the line lugs on the Gateway itself, though.
Once that is done, we can address load shedding.  Since we have the transfer switch upstream of the Gateway, we can simply use the Backup Gateway's load shed contacts to break the Y wire circuit from your thermostat to whichever air conditioner you want to be able to run on the generator; that way, the air conditioner won't run if the Backup Gateway isn't seeing some form of power on the grid terminals, whether it be from the grid proper or from your genset.

Thanks! recharging Powerwall isn't supported because the AC from the genset isn't clean enough power. Powerwall can be configured to see the genset and reduce its output based on its supply as well as supplement it, but no charging. I'll have to continue researching, but seems the MTS will have to move upstream.
